# Contraer y expandir en Bootstrap 4.3 - Collapse

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap

Al momento de pinchar cualquiera de los botones efectivamente expande la información y me muestra la info, sin embargo, puedo contraer con el mismo botón, pero, quisiera que al presionar otro botón me contraiga el que está expandido y me muestre solo la info del botón que acabo de pinchar. algo similar a lo que hace el componente *Accordion* de *Bootstrap*.
PD: *El codigo lo estoy utilixando con la plantilla de Bootstrap V. 4.3*

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseE1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Boton 1
          </a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseE2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
            Boton 2
          </a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseE3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample3">
            Boton 2
          </a>


<div class="collapse" id="collapseE1">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richar
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseE2">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delen
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseE3">
  <div class="card card-body">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delen
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En base a lo que entendí puedes utilizar la siguiente función en `JQuery` para realizar lo que pides:

```js
$('.btn-primary').on('click', function () {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseE1" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Boton 1
          </a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseE2" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample2">
            Boton 2
          </a>
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseE3" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample3">
            Boton 3
          </a>


<div class="collapse" id="collapseE1">
  <div class="card card-body">
    1Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richar
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseE2">
  <div class="card card-body">
    2Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delen
  </div>
</div>
<div class="collapse" id="collapseE3">
  <div class="card card-body">
    3Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Delen
  </div>
</div>
```

Toma en cuenta que se utilizó la clase `.btn-primary` para hacer referencia a los botones, una vez se les da `click` buscará los divs con la clase `collapse` y los ocultará con el `toggle`.

Te anexo rutas de `JQuery` para que lo agregues a tu solución:
https://code.jquery.com/

Es cuestión de usar el siguiente código CDN:

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BJeo0qm959uMBGb65z40ejJYGSgR7REI4+CW1fNKwOg="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Espero te ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Pero al pasar el script `$('.btn-primary').on('click', function () {
    $('.collapse').collapse('hide');
});` a mi codigo no funciona. Sabes por qué?

Comment: toma en cuenta que debes contar con la librería de JQuery como el que se muestra en el código, ejemplo: "<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>"

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta, agregué la ruta a JQuery por si te interesa, pero es cuestión de agregar el "<script>" que coloqué a tu solución.